# PHP preg_replace string – contents within brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm struggling to understand PHP `preg_replace` and wondered if you could offer any guidance on how to work out how to keep the word within the brackets but remove everything else from this string:

```
Events (Road)
```

So it would return:

```
Road
```

I'm keen to learn so don't just need the answer but need to understand how it's possible.

I know how to remove the words within the brackets (and the brackets) with:

```
trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', 'Events (Road)')
```

Cheers,
R

Comment: expected output please?

Comment: Sorry, just simply 'Road'. I'll update question.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think he want to remain word inside `()`. rest he want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to capture the characters within the parentheses and then replace everything else with that.  `$1` is a back-reference to the first capture group `()`:

```
preg_replace('/.*\(([^)]*)\)/', '$1', 'Events (Road)');
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IYqo4U-8NzPFU3QG)